# 3 Image links won't go apart

Tags: html, css

I just found out how to center whats in my div with a bit of a difficulty.

So i have created a footer with 1 main div, which contains a paragraph and 1 div. Paragraph is for text (copyright blah blah blah; more in the code) and the div for 3 images which I want to be pulled apart horizontally (twitter page, facebook page, skype link. 3 icon images, want them to be pulled apart with a width)

My index code looks like this(footer only):

```
<div id="footertop">
    <p class="copyrights"> GALAXIS WORKS © 2013 </p>

    <div align="center" id="icons">
    <a href="http://twitt....." target="_blank" class="twittericon"><img src="images/logo/twittericon.png"></a>
    <a href="http://twit...." tagret="_blank" class="fbicon"><img src="images/logo/fbicon.png"/></a>
    <a href="http://twit...." tagret="_blank" class="skypeicon"><img src="images/logo/skypeicon.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

(links been shortened to dots to not promote my twitter page)

My CSS looks like this:

```
    #footertop {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #303030; 
}

    .copyrights {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: "Century Gothic";
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #FFF; 
}
    #icons {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: inline;
        width: 10em; 
}
```

There could be silly mistake there somewhere, but I really can't spot it!

Comment: I don't think you are asking the question properly ? Explain properly what you want ?

Comment: you want the icons to be aside or below the copy?

Comment: Do you want the icons in center of div ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need to do is add a margin to the `<a>` elements of your code. This will allow you to customize the spacing between each image. Something like this should do the trick:

```
#icons a {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorted it out with:

#icons a {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 display: inline;
}

Comment: Anyway i can actually move it abit down? As it is really close to my paragraph above it!

Comment: use `margin-top` to adjust the spacing above the `<a>` elements.

Comment: It didn't want to work, but i resized my footer to make it smaller and it looks perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    #icons {
        display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
 #icons {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em; 
}

  #icons a{
  float:left;
}
```